# RingCentral JavaScript SDK Handle Redirect URI points to local JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, ringcentral

[RingCentral JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js) handle redirect URI point to local JavaScript function

As-per Doc, they give option

> RingCentral.SDK.handleLoginRedirect()

but dont know how to use that

```
var SDK = require('ringcentral');
rcsdk = new SDK({
        server: SDK.server.sandbox,
        appKey: '_app_key',
        appSecret: 'app_password',
        redirectUri: ''
    })
function handleredirectURI(){
//handle redirections
}
```

We need points out our `handleredirectURI` function
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Per the documentation. The context is 3-legged oAuth. Here is a demo: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-demos-oauth/tree/master/javascript

However the demo doesn't use the `handleredirectURI` method. Which means that the method is simply an utility method and it's not required to use it.

For the usage of `handleredirectURI`, I will come back and update my answer later.

**Update**

Here is the source code for `handleredirectURI`: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js/blob/669b7d06254d3620c5a5f24c94b401aa862be948/src/SDK.js#L115-L124

You can see that the method parses `win.location` to get some useful data and `postMessage` back to its opener.

Unit tests for `handleredirectURI`: https://github.com/ringcentral/ringcentral-js/blob/669b7d06254d3620c5a5f24c94b401aa862be948/src/SDK-spec.js#L27-L63

**Update 2**

I read `handleredirectURI`' source code, unit tests, sample code again and I think its usage is just like what is written in its documentation:

> #### Popup Setup
>
> This setup is good when your app is rendered as a widget on a third-party sites.
>
> If you would like to simply open RingCentral login pages in a popup, you may use the following short-hand in your app's login page:

```
var platform = rcsdk.platform();
var loginUrl = platform.loginUrl({implicit: true}); // implicit parameter is optional, default false
platform
    .loginWindow({url: loginUrl}) // this method also allows to supply more options to control window position
    .then(function (loginOptions){
        return platform.login(loginOptions);
    })
    .then(...)
    .catch(...);
```

> In this case your landing page (the one to which Redirect URI points) need to call the following code:

```
RingCentral.SDK.handleLoginRedirect();
```

**Explained:**

- Run the first code snippet to open the login popup.
- In the redirected to page, run the second code snippet (that one line of code) to get everything else done.
- After that the authorization part is done and you can invoke other APIs.

Let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thanks for your response let me check and  will update you

Comment: if we use RingCentral.SDK.handleLoginRedirect() the method redirectUri not required one right ?

Comment: Which `redirectUri` method do you mean? Or you can show me what you have and where you are stuck.

Comment: I mean when we crate app that ask redirecturl

Comment: `redirectyUri` is mandatory as long as you want to use 3-legged oauth. `RingCentral.SDK.handleLoginRedirect();` is supposed to be executed in the redirected-to page. It has no where to execute if you omit `redirectUri` when you create app.